# How do I change the color of the line in an angular material input?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm putting the inputs against a dark background and you can't see the black, how do I change it to white from the angular themes?
Attached is a screenshot to illustrate my point:
[image: bad image]

I've googled the issue to no avail, I think its because I don't know what the name of the line is.

PS: I cannot directly change it with ::deep selector because I still need the error colors to show.

I added a border at the bottom but it seems to be different because now the error state is in addition to the box.

[image: err]

Comment: please share your html and css code?

Answer (score 0):

That must be a input border, apply this css on the input

```
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
```

Comment: close but no cigar :)